# drawing AC amplification diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to draw a diagram, showing the AC amplification with an NPN transistor. I think I remember that I saw an example of this with tex, but can't find it.

It should look like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help

Edit: Found a way by searching for "diagram rotation" after searching half an hour by the technical terms. However I do remember some really nice looking example (both output and code), so I leave the question open for now.

[How to rotate a pgfplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134904/how-to-rotate-a-pgfplot)

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way by searching for "diagram rotation" after searching half an hour by the technical terms. However I do remember some really nice looking example (both output and code), so I leave the question open for now.

[How to rotate a pgfplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134904/how-to-rotate-a-pgfplot)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147185)

Comment: This is actually the answer I was looking for. I only remember another variation, which I couldn't find, but this doesn't change the original post.

Comment: This is still just a comment.  To be answer, you would show how to implement to achieve the result you request.

Comment: I found what I needed, so there isn't really any point in updating the answer/post when it gets deleted anyway. Wouldn't help anybody else with the same problem this way